# How to disable certificate validation for LDAP authentication on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, ldap, openldap

I am writing a sample client (coded in C/C++) for authenticating user via LDAP. The client is developed for both Windows and Linux.

For Linux, I am using [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) library compiled with `--with-tls` (OpenSSL). For authenticating user via an encrypted channel I am skipping the server-client certificate validation. To do so, I am setting the ldap option to :

```
option = LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_NEVER;
returnCode = ldap_set_option(vLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, &option);

if(returnCode != LDAP_OPT_SUCCESS){
    return FALSE;
}
```

This will skip the certification validation and will always allow client to authenticate.

However, on Windows I am using wldap.dll for the application. I am not able to figure out how to disable the server-client certificate validation for LDAP over an encrypted connection.

when I run through:

```
returnCode = ldap_set_option(vLdapConnection, LDAP_OPT_SSL, LDAP_OPT_ON);
```

the returnCode is always to set to `LDAP_SERVER_DOWN = 0x51`

**How to disable client certificate validation for LDAP with Wldap32.dll on Windows??**

Comment: Why? All you're accomplishing with this is lowering the security. If your LDAP server has a CA-signed certificate none of this should be necessary. If you don't want it secure why use SSL at all?

Comment: This is just for an early testing purpose. We do not have any CA-signed certificates to test at this moment.

Comment: I suggest you skip it. Making it work the wrong way is of no interest. Use plaintext until you get a certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Session Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367019%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), specifically `LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE`.  It lets you specify a callback function to validate the server certificate.